# convert hex encoded bytes string to something readable

Tags: nami-wallet, decode, bytes

I'm using nami wallet's api, and if I call cardano.getUsedAddresses() it return a "hex encoded bytes string" and I would like to  know how I can convert that to something readable

Answer (score 0):

First, `getUsedAddresses()` returns a **list** of all used (included in some on-chain transaction) addresses controlled by the wallet<sup>1</sup>.

To decode, can use [`decodeHexAddress`](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-connect-with-wallet/blob/main/src/utils/wallet.ts#L19) on `getUsedAddresses()` elements.

---

<sup>1</sup> https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip30/#apigetusedaddressespaginatepaginateundefinedpromiseaddress

Comment: that file is written in typescript. I have used javascript. should I switch to typescript?

Comment: Entirely up to you. You can import this function inside your **JS** project, like so: `import { decodeHexAddress } from '@cardano-foundation/cardano-connect-with-wallet'`.